# Rename Files in google Drive Using Google Sheet Links or by Changing the Google Script for Document Upload

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script installed that automatically attaches the link to a Google Drive file in a cell in Google Sheets. Here is what the script looks like this:

```js
// Use this code for Google Docs, Slides, Forms, or Sheets.
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
 .createMenu('Upload File Tutorial')
 .addItem('Attachment', 'openAttachmentDialog')
 .addToUi();
}
function openAttachmentDialog() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('UploadFile');
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
 .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
}
function saveFile(obj) {
 var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
 var file = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID HERE").createFile(blob);
 var cellFormula = 'hyperlink("' + file.getUrl() + '";"' + file.getName() + '")';
 
 var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var selection = activeSheet.getSelection();
 var cell = selection.getCurrentCell();
 cell.setFormula(cellFormula);
 
 return file.getId();
}
```

and this is the corresponding HTML script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <script>
    function getFiles() {
      document.getElementById("uploadButton").disabled = true;
      const progressText = document.getElementById("progress");
      const f = document.getElementById('files');
      var uploadCompletedCount = 0;
      progressText.innerHTML = "Uploading file " + (uploadCompletedCount + 1) + "/" + [...f.files].length + "";
      [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = (e) => {
          const data = e.target.result.split(",");
          const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {
            uploadCompletedCount++;
            progressText.innerHTML = "Upload completed";
            if (uploadCompletedCount >= [...f.files].length){
              google.script.host.close();
            }
            else{
              progressText.innerHTML = "Uploading file " + (uploadCompletedCount + 1) + "/" + [...f.files].length + "";
            }
          }).saveFile(obj);
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <!-- <input type="file" name="upload" id="files" multiple/> -->
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="files"/> <!-- I expect to up load only one file -->
    <input type='button' id="uploadButton" value='Upload' onclick='getFiles()' class="action"> 
    <br><br>
    <div id="progress"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of List]

Can I update the script somehow to change the name of the file uploaded to Google Drive from Google Sheets:
I have a list of correct names for the files A2:A and links to the files in D2:D but i don't know how to change the name of the file(Using the Information from Cells A2:A, can someone assist me to update the code. I am looking for a solution to change the name of the file automatically based on a corresponding cell in column A.

I found this code on the web but it was for a bulk rename https://dev.to/ismailisimba/how-to-rename-a-bunch-of-files-in-google-drive-using-google-sheets-and-apps-script-1ed5

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It looks that the code included is not directly related to what you are asking. Instead of this code show what you tried, also be more clear about why the code you found doesn't work for you or describe how do you want to use the script.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution, when you copy scripts from here.